# Azure DevOps unable to pull repository

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

Hey all I've been banging my head for 2 days on this issue. all of our auzre dev ops piplines have stopped being able to build for no reason I can find. The error below says invalid clientid or client secret but I can't figure out what that is referencing.

```
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8763131Z ##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/docker'
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8763506Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/docker arg: pull`
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8764166Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/docker arg: ***/php8-base:latest
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8764916Z ##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/docker
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8765285Z ##[debug]arguments:
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8765637Z ##[debug]   pull
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8766055Z ##[debug]   ***/php8-base:latest
2023-07-18T13:20:47.8766779Z [command]/usr/bin/docker pull ***/php8-base:latest
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4683424Z Error response from daemon: Head "https://***/v2/php8-base/manifests/latest": unauthorized: Invalid clientid or client secret.
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4707635Z ##[debug]An error was found pulling the image ***/php8-base:latest, the command output was Error response from daemon: Head "https://***/v2/php8-base/manifests/latest": unauthorized: Invalid clientid or client secret.

2023-07-18T13:20:53.4708257Z ##[debug]which '/usr/bin/docker'
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4709275Z ##[debug]found: '/usr/bin/docker'
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4709633Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/docker arg: inspect
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4710044Z ##[debug]/usr/bin/docker arg: ***/php8-base:latest
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4710414Z ##[debug]exec tool: /usr/bin/docker
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4710746Z ##[debug]arguments:
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4711066Z ##[debug]   inspect
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4711449Z ##[debug]   ***/php8-base:latest
2023-07-18T13:20:53.4712071Z [command]/usr/bin/docker inspect ***/php8-base:latest
2023-07-18T13:20:53.5095970Z Error: No such object: ***/php8-base:latest
```

Here is my pipline file
I thin k the issue is somewhere in the SSH building section that's the file I tried replacing but got the same issue as before.

````
        # Docker
    # Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
    # https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker
    
    trigger:
    - develop
    
    resources:
    - repo: self
    
    variables:
      # Variable group definition for specific site
    - group: *******-dev
      # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
    - name: dockerRegistryServiceConnection
      value: '*********-****-****-****-***********'
    - name: imageRepository
      value: '$(IMAGE_NAME)'
    - name: containerRegistry
      value: '***********.azurecr.io'
    - name: dockerfilePath
      value: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
    - name: tag
      value: '$(Build.BuildId)'
      # Agent VM image name
    - name: vmImageName
      value: 'ubuntu-latest'
    - name: image
      value: '$(Build.BuildId)'
    
    # ----------------
    # Build stage, dockerbuild and ACR tag/push
    # ----------------
    
    stages:
    - stage: Build
      displayName: Build and push stage
      jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        variables:
        - group: *******-dev
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
    # ----------------
    # Stage ssh keys from securefiles
    # ----------------
    
        - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
          name: satis_id_rsa
          inputs:
            secureFile: satis_id_rsa
    
    # ----------------
    # Setup ssh key from secure file used by dockerbuild for azure repo access, also used by satis for repo access
    # ----------------
    
        - task: CmdLine@2
          displayName: ssh key setup for dockerbuild
          inputs:
            script: |
              AZURE_ID_RSA=$(cat $(satis_id_rsa.secureFilePath) | base64 -w 0)
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AZURE_ID_RSA;issecret=true]$AZURE_ID_RSA"
    
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Build container image from dockerfile
          inputs:
            command: build
            repository: $(imageRepository)
            dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
            containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
            arguments: --build-arg COMPOSER_REPO_URL=$(COMPOSER_REPO_URL) --build-arg AZURE_ID_RSA=$(AZURE_ID_RSA)
            tags: |
              $(tag)
              latest
        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: Push container image from dockerfile
          inputs:
            command: push
            repository: $(imageRepository)
            containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
            tags: |
              $(tag)
              latest
    
    # ----------------
    # Deploy stage, deploys to aks cluster
    # ----------------
    
    - stage: Deploy_dev
      displayName: Deploy to dev
      jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy_dev
        displayName: Deploy_dev
        variables:
        - group: ******-dev
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        environment: '******-dev'
        strategy: 
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: self
    
    # ----------------
    # task to replace vars in aks-*.yml files, based on site var group
    # ----------------
    
              - task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
                displayName: 'Prepare aks-*.yaml manifest file'
                inputs:
                  targetFiles: 'pipeline/aks-*.yml'
                  tokenPrefix: ___
                  tokenSuffix: ___
    
    # ----------------
    # task to deploy site k8s config to aks cluster
    # ----------------
    
              - task: Kubernetes@1
                displayName: Deploy latest image to aks cluster
                inputs:
                  connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
                  kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '**************************'
                  namespace: '$(SITE_NAME)'
                  command: 'apply'
                  useConfigurationFile: true
                  configuration: 'pipeline/aks-deployment.yml'
                  secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
                  containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
    ```
````

Google searches suggest that our principle service connection expired but I checked and it was still valid(we are using Azure Resource Manager). I re-generated it anyway just to be sure but still no luck. Someone suggested that our SSH key might be expired so I tried replacing the one in our variable secret files but that also failed with the same error. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Here is the service connection metioned in the comments
[image: service connection]

Comment: Share your pipeline.

Comment: Added the pipline file. Thanks

Comment: My guess would be the data stored in the service connection is incorrect: `containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)`

Comment: @jessehouwing thats good thought, I checked and that ID points to the service connection(screenshot added to post can't figure out how to put it in a comment) which as far as I can tell is configured correctly. I'm brand new at this learning as I go and that is more information than I knew before so thanks!

Comment: I also just tried it with another docker service connection that looks identical to the one above but with a different resource ID and got my same orriginal error